# Should return the same value 3 consecutives calls

Tags: scala

I have an exercise to be resolved in Scala. I need to make a method that decides if it possible to play soccer some day. It depends of rain or not.
The probability of rain is less than 20%. If some day rain, then the following two days also will rain.
So, we will have 3 consecutive days or rain. I did this:

```
case class Weather() {

  var rainyDay = 0

  def rain = scala.util.Random.nextDouble() <= 0.2

  def canPlay = {
    rainyDay match {
      case 1 | 2 =>{
        rainyDay = rainyDay+1
        false
      }
      case _ => {
        rain match {
          case true => {
            rainyDay = 1
            false
          }
          case _ => true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tested it and works fine, but I wonder if there is any better way to do it?

(Sorry about my english)

Comment: Few comments: why a `case class`? Also, it's often useful to think about your program "simply" in terms of inputs and outputs. What would your input be? What's the output (a a boolean value, I suppose)

Answer (score 4):

If you're on Scala 2.13.x then you might simply `unfold()` over an infinite `Iterator`.

```
case class Weather() {
  private val canPlayDay = Iterator.unfold(0)(state => Some {
    if (state > 0) (false, state-1)
    else if (util.Random.nextDouble() <= 0.2) (false, 2)
    else (true, 0)
  })

  def canPlay() : Boolean = canPlayDay.next()
}
```

Notice: no `var` required.